# h5py setup.py on Mac: hdf5.h file not found

Tags: macos, gcc, hdf5, h5py

I am building h5py on Mac, following instructions "Building against Parallel HDF5" in this link: http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/build.html

```
$ export CC=mpicc
$ python setup.py configure --mpi
$ sudo python setup.py build
```

I get this error:

```
h5py-2.5.0/h5py/api_compat.h:27:10: fatal error: 'hdf5.h' file not found
```

What should I do? If I need to install some dev version of HDF5, how can I do it on Mac?

Answer (score 22):

I was getting this same error message yesterday, doing a general installation of HDF5 (not building against parallel). I was able to get around it by using `Homebrew` (a package manager for OS X that can be found here: http://brew.sh/).

Once you've installed `Homebrew` (if you don't already have it), the command is `brew install hdf5`.

Comment: Command I had to execute ended up being `brew install homebrew/science/hdf5`

Comment: Some things have changed in 6 years. Just got the following error message:
`Error: homebrew/science was deprecated. This tap is now empty and all its contents were either deleted or migrated.`

Answer (score 3):

You can find hdf5.h lib in your Unix and set in CPATH varible

freebsd 11 example:

```
>> find /usr -iname "*hdf5.h*"  
<< /usr/local/include/hdf5.h
>> export CPATH="/usr/local/include/"
```

Then you can compile that you need

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged; would you mind explaining what you're doing so future readers can more easily understand?